# Return type mismatch of Visual C++

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, types, arrays

I have a following return type in Visual C++:

```
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) unsigned char* _cdecl 
                                          getname(LPCTSTR Track1, int len)
```

I have written the following code to get the right value of `unsigned char*` in C#:

```
[DllImport(_dllLocation, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
 public static extern byte[] getname(string track1, int len);
```

I called the above method from another .cs file with the following code:

```
string track = "hello12345"; 
byte[] name = UnsafeNativeMethods.getname(track, 160);
```

Please tell what i am doing wrong here, also please check the parameter datatype i.e. `LPCTSTR` and `string`.

Is `unsigned char*` equivalent to `byte[]`. If so then why I am getting the wrong value in C# file where in C++ it is correct.

### Edit:

After some suggestion through comments i have changed the `byte name` to `byte[] name` but it shows me following exception:

```
A first chance exception of type 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.MarshalDirectiveException' occurred in DecryptionWS.dll
A first chance exception of type 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.MarshalDirectiveException' occurred in DecryptionWS.dll
A first chance exception of type 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.MarshalDirectiveException' occurred in   System.ServiceModel.dll
A first chance exception of type 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.MarshalDirectiveException' occurred in System.ServiceModel.dll
```

Comment: Your `getname` extern method returns a byte but you use it like a `byte[]`. Is it a byte or byte[]?

Comment: My mistake, Now i edited it

Comment: I also tried it :
    `byte[] name = UnsafeNativeMethods.getname(track, 160);`
    `Console.Writeline (name);`
but it halt the program and throw `System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.ServiceModel.Web.dll`

Comment: `Console.WriteLine(name)` will only print `System.Byte[]`. What value are you expecting? If you're expecting a string, you need to use `System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(name)` (or whichever encoding format you used).

Comment: @keyboardP please see the edit section of code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`unsigned char*` and `byte[]` are not exactly equivalent.  An `unsigned char*` is a pointer to  bytes, but a `byte[]` is an array of bytes with a *known length*.  An `unsigned char*` has no known length.  The .Net marshaller cannot marshal directly from an `unsigned char*` to a `byte[]` because it does not know the length of the buffer.

So you will have to manually marshall the return value:

1. Change your p/Invoke function definition to return an `IntPtr` (that is a generic pointer value)`
2. Use [Marhsal.Copy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms146631.aspx) to copy from the `IntPtr` to a byte array.

Exmaple:

```
[DllImport(_dllLocation, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public static extern IntPtr getname(string track1, int len);


string track = "hello12345"; 
IntPtr namePtr = UnsafeNativeMethods.getname(track, 160);
Byte[] name = new Byte[/* some size here - it is not clear how*/];
Marshal.Copy(namePtr, name, 0, name.Length);
```

Comment: I put the size `160` , then i print the `name` in output and it shows me: `System.Byte[]`. What does it mean?

Comment: `.ToString()` on a any array type returns the the name of the type, in this case `System.Byte[]`.  What do you expect in the contents of the byte array.  A string?

Comment: Finally i want to convert this `name` variable into `Hex` string. But i am not able to get the data from `name` variable. How should i do thaT?

Comment: @AmitPal See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/311165/how-do-you-convert-byte-array-to-hexadecimal-string-and-vice-versa